# Showing element in front of common backdrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We want to find a solution to show just the green box in front of the backdrop (#back). And this without modifying the html.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="body" style="z-index:1;position:relative;">

  <div id="div1" style="z-index:4;position:relative;">
  </div>

  <div style="z-index:4;background-color: red;  width: 70px;position:relative;height: 70px;">
    <div id="div2" style="z-index:7;background-color:green;position:relative;">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="back" style="z-index:5;">
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#body {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#div1 {
  position:relative;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#back {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

There is a fiddle of our problem :

https://jsfiddle.net/ruj23c60/3/

Comment: Hi you mean you want your background is green isn't it ?????

Comment: You need to give `z-index:3` to `#back`. (less than `#div2` parent div) then you  can make it front of `#back`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div style="z-index:4;background-color: red;  width: 70px;height: 70px;">
    <div id="div2" style="z-index:7;background-color:green;position:relative;">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Removing the style `position: relative` from the parent of `#div2` is sufficient already

Answer (score 0):

There are two way as i know.

**First:**

You need to give `z-index:3` to `#back`. (less than `#div2` parent div) then you can make it front of `#back`

But this way whole div come in front of black(`#back`) div.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruj23c60/5/)

**Second:**

Make `position:adsolute;` to `#div2` and remove `position:relative;` from it's parent.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruj23c60/6/)

**Note:** I have comment `opacity: 0.7;` from `#back` to understand properly.